# Overfitting when fine-tuning BERT sentiment analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, overfitting-underfitting

I am newbie to Machine Learning in general. I am currently trying to follow a tutorial on sentiment analysis using BERT and Transformers https://curiousily.com/posts/sentiment-analysis-with-bert-and-hugging-face-using-pytorch-and-python/

However when I train the model it has appeared that the model is overfitting
[image: Train/val loss & accuracy]

I do not know how to fix this. I have tried lowering amount of epochs, increasing batch size , shuffling my data (which is ordered) and increasing the validation split. So far nothing has worked. I have even tried changing different learning rate but the one I am using now is the smallest.

Below is my code:

```
PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

MAX_LEN = 40

#Make a PyTorch dataset
class FIDataset(Dataset):

  def __init__(self, texts, targets, tokenizer, max_len):

    self.texts = texts

    self.targets = targets

    self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    self.max_len = max_len

  def __len__(self):

    return len(self.texts)

  def __getitem__(self, item):

    text = str(self.texts[item])

    target = self.targets[item]

    encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(

      text,

      add_special_tokens=True,

      max_length=self.max_len,

      return_token_type_ids=False,

      pad_to_max_length=True,

      return_attention_mask=True,

      return_tensors='pt',

    )

    return {

      'text': text,

      'input_ids': encoding['input_ids'].flatten(),

      'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),

      'targets': torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long)

    }

#split test and train
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(

  df,

  test_size=0.1,

  random_state=RANDOM_SEED

)

df_val, df_test = train_test_split(

  df_test,

  test_size=0.5,

  random_state=RANDOM_SEED

)


#data loader function
def create_data_loader(df, tokenizer, max_len, batch_size):

  ds = FIDataset(

    texts=df.content.to_numpy(),

    targets=df.sentiment.to_numpy(),

    tokenizer=tokenizer,

    max_len=max_len

  )

  return DataLoader(

    ds,

    batch_size=batch_size,

    num_workers=4

  )

BATCH_SIZE = 32

#Load data into train, test, val
train_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_train, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

val_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_val, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

test_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_test, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

#Bert model loading
bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

# Sentiment Classifier based on Bert model just loaded
class SentimentClassifier(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, n_classes):

    super(SentimentClassifier, self).__init__()

    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

    self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)

    self.out = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    returned = self.bert(
        
        input_ids=input_ids,
        attention_mask=attention_mask
    )
    pooled_output = returned["pooler_output"]
    output = self.drop(pooled_output)
    
    return self.out(output)

#Create a Classifier instance and move to GPU
model = SentimentClassifier(3)

model = model.to(device)

#Optimize with AdamW
EPOCHS = 6

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, correct_bias=False)

total_steps = len(train_data_loader) * EPOCHS

scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(

  optimizer,

  num_warmup_steps=0,

  num_training_steps=total_steps

)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

#Train each Epoch function
def train_epoch(

  model,

  data_loader,

  loss_fn,

  optimizer,

  device,

  scheduler,

  n_examples

):

  model = model.train()

  losses = []

  correct_predictions = 0

  for d in data_loader:

    input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)

    attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)

    targets = d["targets"].to(device)

    outputs = model(

      input_ids=input_ids,

      attention_mask=attention_mask

    )

    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)

    loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)

    correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)

    losses.append(loss.item())

    loss.backward()

    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)

    optimizer.step()

    scheduler.step()

    optimizer.zero_grad()

  return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)

import torch

history = defaultdict(list)

best_accuracy = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

      print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')

      print('-' * 10)

      train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(

        model,

        train_data_loader,

        loss_fn,

        optimizer,

        device,

        scheduler,

        len(df_train)

      )

      print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')

      val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(

        model,

        val_data_loader,

        loss_fn,

        device,

        len(df_val)

      )

      print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}')

      print()

      history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)

      history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)

      history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)

      history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

      if val_acc > best_accuracy:

        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')

        best_accuracy = val_acc
```

Answer (score 7):

Broadly speaking, to reduce overfitting, you can:

1. increase regularization
2. reduce model complexity
3. perform early stopping
4. increase training data

From what you've written, you've already tried 3 and 4. In the case of neural networks, you can increase regularization by increasing dropout. You already have the code for it.

```py
# NOTE: You don't need bert_model here since you're creating one inside
# of SentimentClassifier.
#bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

# Sentiment Classifier based on Bert model just loaded
class SentimentClassifier(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, n_classes):

    super(SentimentClassifier, self).__init__()

    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

    self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.1) # <-- INCREASE THIS VALUE

    self.out = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
```

I'd recommend trying higher values of the `Dropout` probability, as I noted in your code above ("INCREASE THIS VALUE"). Keep track of the Dropout probability and the resulting observed overfitting. Try probability values of `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5`.

Usually, I've found that dropout over 0.5 doesn't do much good.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. I have tried to replace the old data with new data of customers review from our store and the situation is now that my training accuracy is <1% while the test accuracy hovers around 60%- Do you have some idea how to fix this or is it that our data is entirely not suitable for Bert?

Comment: Are you still trying to do sentiment analysis? It's unlikely that BERT is at fault. Did you double-check your new dataset? Is the data in `utf-8`? Are you able to parse the sentences and the ground-truth scores from that data? Can you see the data in your `Dataset` and `Dataloader`, and is what you expect?

Comment: Hello I cannot encode my texts as utf-8 because they are not English but Finnish. Currently the encoding is ISO-8859-1. I have printed out a part of the dataset df.head() and they look correct. I have also tried to have the labeled data the same exact amount (i.e negative = positive = neutral = 2247 samples. in total 6741 samples)

Comment: Ok. You should have said you had a Finnish dataset in the first place. BERT is pre-trained on largely English text. I googled "BERT Finnish" and found several hits for new BERT models that have been pre-trained on Finnish. You should do the same.

Comment: Hello, as you can see in my code I used a Finnish Bert model